# iPhone shows Personal Hotspot icon as off but it still has users connected

Tags: iphone, wifi, software-update

The iphone 7 on our account turns hotspot off when out of range of wifi but still showing users connected. In fact the users are connected but hot spot icon is off. Huge amounts of Data used. My Wife ran out of Data of 15 GB after a few days, her normal usage is 5 to 10 GB for the Month. Turning airplane mode on will disconnect all users.

This appears to have started after an update last week (Ver 12.0.1) at least we never saw the problem before and I know we never used this much data before.

Comment: Ron, would you please clarify how does the iPhone “turns hotspot off when out of range of WiFi”? In order to work, Personal Hotspot disconnects from WiFi and shares your mobile data plan. Any user that has ever connected to it may reconnect when you turn it on, and treat it as an unmetered connection, updating apps, cloud services, etc.